# Templated Manual Destructor Call Not Working

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, destructor

I want to destroy the templated object, but keep the allocated memory to be filled. Unfortunately, the destructor of the object is never called, and stepping through the code, it skips the manual call.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename type> class TestClass
{
    private:

        type *data;

    public:

        TestClass();
        ~TestClass();

        template <typename T> void Set(T &&element);
        void Replace();
};


template <typename type> TestClass<type>::TestClass()
{
    data = reinterpret_cast<type *>(new char[sizeof(type)]);;
}

template <typename type> TestClass<type>::~TestClass()
{
}

template <typename type> template <typename T> void TestClass<type>::Set(T &&element)
{
    new(data) type(static_cast<T &&>(element));
}

template <typename type> void TestClass<type>::Replace()
{
    type *pointer = reinterpret_cast<type *>(&data[0]);
    pointer->~type();

    //Fill with data
}

class MyClass
{
    public:

        MyClass()
        {
        }

        ~MyClass()
        {
            std::cout << "Called" << "\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass *myClass = new MyClass();

    TestClass<MyClass *> myObject;

    myObject.Set(myClass);
    myObject.Replace();

    return 0;
}
```

I have tested this in VS 2017 and on an online C++ compiler. Both skip the pointer->~type(); when stepping through and the destructor is never called.

Edit: Rewrote code which now reproduces the error.

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: I've updated the code to show a stripped down version, but as far as being able to just compile it, I'm afraid that would take some doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow templates to deal generally with types, C++ allows a `obj.~type()` or `ptr->~type()` syntax even when the type is not a class type (but not for an array type).  The meaning is the same as whatever would happen to an automatic object of that type at the end of its scope: if it is a class type, the destructor is called, and if not, nothing happens.  For the case when the type is not a class type, this syntax is called a [pseudo-destructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.dtor).

Now looking at your example, you're using the class template specialization `TestClass<MyClass*>`. So in the instantiation of the member definition for `TestClass<type>::Replace()`, `type` is an alias for `MyClass*`.  The statement

```
type *pointer = reinterpret_cast<type *>(&data[0]);
```

defines a variable of type `type*`, which is `MyClass**`. (The right-hand side is confusing: `&data[0]` is the same as `data` assuming it points at something, and both expressions already have type `type*`.)

The statement

```
pointer->~type();
```

says to destroy the object of type `type` which `pointer` points at.  That is, it says to destroy the object of type `MyClass*` which is `*pointer`.  `MyClass*` is not a class type; it is a pointer type.  So this is a call to a pseudo-destructor, and absolutely nothing happens.

There's not enough context to say for certain how this would be fixed, but perhaps you need to use `TestClass<MyClass>` instead of `TestClass<MyClass*>`? (Also, in real code don't forget the Rule Of Five/Rule Of Three.)

Comment: This made so much sense and explains so much. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It does call destructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class Type
{
    public:
    ~Type()
    {
        std::cout<< __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    }
};


template <typename type> class MyClass
{
    private:

        type *data;

    public:

        MyClass();
        ~MyClass(){}

        void Replace();
};


template <typename type> MyClass<type>::MyClass()
{
    data =  reinterpret_cast<type *>(new char[sizeof(type)]);;
}


template <typename type> void MyClass<type>::Replace()
{
    type *pointer = &data[0];
    pointer->~type();

    //Fill with replacement data
}
int main()
{

    MyClass<Type> myClass;

    std::cout <<"Before destruction\n";
myClass.Replace();
std::cout << "After destruction\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code does work so I have managed to cobble together an example that reproduces the error on multiple compilers.